# Quartz iPhone drawRect not called

Tags: iphone, quartz-graphics, drawrect

I am subclassing a UIView and am calling it via a detail view controller.  When I load it, it shows up with the right dimensions and positioning, however it is just a black square...  When I just put a UIView into interface builder with the class, it works.  I don't think draw rect is called.  Heres my code:

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
        [self setNeedsDisplay];
    }
    return self;
}


- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    // Drawing code

    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context, 255.0, 255.0, 0, 1);
    CGContextStrokeRect(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 50));
}
```

and I call it like so:

```
 GameBox *boxy = [[GameBox alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, 50, 50, 50)];
    [self.view addSubview: boxy];
```

Comment: why are you calling setneedsdisplay in init? this is incorrect, at the point of init it hasnt been added to any view, and the view has not loaded..

Comment: Then how do I get the thing to show up not black?  I have tried it without setting setneedsdisplay

Comment: first the color is betwen 0 and 1, not 255...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are setting your fill color but you are stroking a rect.  You need to set the stroke color: `CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor`